# Add new variable created with mutate_ to data frame instead of creating a tibble

Tags: r, dplyr

My attempt to add a new column to a dataframe with mutate gave me a tibble with the new variable, but did not add the variable as a new column in the dataframe (which is what I want to do).

I have a data frame with a character variable, `DRUG_GENERIC_NAME`, and created a new logical variable, `Ibuprofen` by combining mutate and str_detect which will be `TRUE` when `IBUPROFEN` is contained in `DRUG_GENERIC_NAME`:

```
mutate(Drug_Table, DRUG_GENERIC_NAME, Ibuprofen = str_detect (Drug_Table$DRUG_GENERIC_NAME,"IBUPROFEN", negate = FALSE))
```

The result was a tibble with the new variable Ibuprofen, but the code did not add the variable to the data frame `Drug_Table`. How can I use this code to add the new variable to the dataframe instead of creating a tibble?

Comment: Assign the result back to the name of the original data frame: `Drug_Table <- mutate(...`

Comment: If you assign the result back it's still going to be converted to a tibble (a tibble is just a slightly modified dataframe, and works exactly the same 95% of the time). There's no real way around that when using `mutate()`, you may just have to get used to the idea of using tibbles.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the compound assignment operator (`%<>%`) from `magrittr` if we don't want to assign it back with `<-`

```
library(magrittr)
Drug_Table %<>%
   mutate(Ibuprofen = str_detect(DRUG_GENERIC_NAME,"IBUPROFEN", negate = FALSE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as Calum You proposed, You have to assign the result to the original data frame using the "<-" operator:

```
Drug_Table <- mutate(Drug_Table, DRUG_GENERIC_NAME, Ibuprofen = str_detect (Drug_Table$DRUG_GENERIC_NAME,"IBUPROFEN", negate = FALSE))
```

If You need the data frame to still be a data.frame (and not a tibble) use as.data.frame()

```
Drug_Table <- as.data.frame(mutate(Drug_Table, DRUG_GENERIC_NAME, Ibuprofen = str_detect (Drug_Table$DRUG_GENERIC_NAME,"IBUPROFEN", negate = FALSE)))
```